# How to get and locally store file uploaded from front end

Tags: node.js

I have a HTML code which accepts a batch name (dropdown), parameters(textarea), email id(test) and a batch file .txt input file (file). When I click 'Submit' in the front end form I see the below in logs:

```
GET /batch?batches=Batch1 - - ms - -
```

I am not sure how can I know and extract & store the file name at server side via NodeJS script? Also whats the way to capture textarea as submitted by user?

```
<form action="batch">
<label for="batch">Select Batch&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<select name="batches" id="batch">
<select name="batches" id="batch">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a batch</option>
    <option value="1">Batch1</option>
    <option value="2">Batch2</option>
    <option value="3">Batch3</option>
    <option value="4">Batch4</option>
    <option value="5">Batch5</option>
</select>
</p>
<br/>
<p>
<label for="binpfile">Batch Input File</label>
<input type="file" id="binpfile" accept=".txt">
</p>
<br/>
<p>
<label for="emailid">E-Mail ID:</label>
<input type="text" id="emailid"><br>
</p>
<br/>
<p class="formfield">
<label for="bparam">Batch Parameters:</label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="bparam" form="usrform">Enter batch param here...</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Below is my NodeJS code: **I see in logs as "User entered Batch1 undefined undefined undefined"**

```
exports.processbatch = function(req, resp) {
    var bname = req.query['batches'];
    var fname = req.query['binpfile'];
    var emailid = req.query['emailid'];
    var bparam = req.query['bparam'];
    console.log ('User entered ' + bname + ' ' + fname + ' ' + emailid + ' ' + bparam);
};
```

Comment: You need to add a `name` to your form fields, note that your select box has a name attribute and that's the only one displaying correctly

Comment: OK after adding name to each HTML element I get the required values - but how do I capture the file and locally store it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not examine the 'req.query' object?

console.log(req);

Comment: I get a long value key list - but how do I capture the file uploaded and locally store it?

Comment: You need to add 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in order for the file upload to work.  Using GET, PUT, POST & DELETE for your form method will allow for better flexibility on the server end to create a robust API and eliminate the need for multiple conditionals to determine the applications course (think GET = search, POST = new record, PUT = update existing record & DELETE = remove record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to handle file upload. in combination of body-parser.

You file get file in req.file after multer complete its task.